# Communication between Client and Server running on two different machines in C# using Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, client-server, ipc

i need Communication between Client and Server running on two different machines  in C# using Visual studio 2010

The main app that is the client app needs to tell the  server app on the server  to start and stop process. and server app needs to tell the main client app when  process has been completed and also of any errors

please give me some suggestion , what is best to use for my application .

Answer (score 0):

The easier form of doing that, I would think on having a database in the middle for communication between the client app and the server.
On the server you would have a service on continuous running, and querying the DB if he should start the process (code) or not. The server will mark that task as Started, and when it finished, it would mark Finished. The client, only need to add new records to a table where the server will look for.